# Meaning of "two empty sets of garments hung opposite each other in a cupboard."

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, literature, interpretation

> ‘Where have you been all day?’ said Philip. ‘I waited for you. Let’s go
> out and eat.’
>
> ‘I’m going on the train. Tonight.’
>
> ‘Wait another couple of days. We’ll fly back.’
>
> She shook her head. The music stopped and the screen was filled with the
> smiling face of a young man.
>
> ‘Course,’ said the man, the boy, ‘an album’s a major statement of where a
> band’s at creatively.’
>
> ‘Aren’t you being a bit iron-clad?’ said Philip. He swung his feet to the
> floor. ‘It’s because I didn’t come back last night, isn’t it.’
>
> ‘Dexter came looking for me.’
>
> ‘Here?’ He laughed, and turned off the television. ‘Bloody Elizabeth.
> Big-mouth.’
>
> ‘I sent him away. He was crying.’
>
> He bent his knees in front of the mirror and flicked his hair about. ‘I can’t
> help you with that one, Athena,’ he said. ‘Jealousy. You’ll have to handle
> that one on your own, I’m afraid.’
>
> He straightened up and faced her. They were like two ghosts, now that
> the blood had gone out of them, **two empty sets of garments hung opposite
> each other in a cupboard**.

*Explain: Athena and philip were in love with each other and now they are not in love with each other.*

Does it mean "as they seemed like two dead person they were like two empty sets of garments hung opposite
each other in a cupboard", the meaning of "empty" is unclear to me.

Source: *The Children's Bach* by Helen Garner

Comment: Isn't it pretty obvious that, if the garments are hanging up, nobody is wearing them, so they are 'empty'?

Comment: Yes, Thank you, I know that but I thought maybe it has special meaning farther than it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a metaphor. Instead of being normal human beings with a body inhabited by a living soul, they seem to have lost all life, resembling ***empty***  garments which do not clothe a body, but hang in a cupboard.

Prompted by James, I will add that this is a particular kind of metaphor called ***simile***:

> *Similes* differ from other metaphors by highlighting the similarities between two things using comparison words such as "like", "as", "so", or " than", while other metaphors create an implicit comparison (i.e. saying something "is" something else). ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simile))

Comment: since they were "like...two empty sets of garments", you could also mention that it is a "simile"

Comment: True, thanks for pointing it out. Will edit.

Comment: Lots of thanks for your answers and comments, I mentioned in my understanding that they seemed like two dead person..., I did not expect negative point!